# How do you get a TemplateRef from a template variable inside another template?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I use [NgBoostrap accordion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/overview).

And I'm trying to retrieve a TemplateRef that is in an ng-template with @ViewChild . The ng-template is an embedded view created by the ngbAccordionBody directive.

See NgBootstrap GitHub for embedded view creation: [ngbAccordionBody](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.directive.ts#L73)

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngbdaccordionbasic-viewchild?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccordion-basic.html) to present my problem.

You'll see that I've found a workaround to my problem.

But I'd like to know if using @ViewChild is possible in this situation. If not, I'd like to know why not.

Comment: Well, IMO the design of the bootstrap component is at fault here. Your workaround is the only way as far as I know, but would you mind explaining why you would want that component as a ViewChild? Why would you need to access the component reference?

Comment: Perhaps you've simplified it, but why use `ng-template` inside at all? It's not needed in your example and without it, it should work. I think you'll have to expand your question a bit more to specify why you're doing it a certain way.

Comment: I've created a simple example to present my problem. In reality, the component is a ng-template that I retrieve and pass to a service that injects it into certain parts of my application.

Comment: @DanielB In my example, I'm using an `ng-template` because that's how the ngb-accordion (See NgBootstrap GitHub for embedded view creation: [ngbAccordionBody](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.directive.ts#L73)) directive works. The directive searches for the first `TemplateRef` with `@ContentChild` and creates an embedded view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was indeed a [bug in the library](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/4623). Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewChild` is not able to find the component instance because it's nested within an `ng-template`.

`@ViewChild` is a decorator in Angular that is used to query and get the first element or the directive matching the selector from the view DOM.
[Angular - @ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

However, it has limitations when it comes to accessing elements/components within an ng-template. The content inside an ng-template is not rendered in the DOM until it's instantiated, and @ViewChild works with the rendered DOM.

In your case, the ng-template is preventing the direct access of the `MyComponent` instance because it's not part of the rendered DOM when `@ViewChild` is looking for it.